# Outlook VSTO Disabling/Repurposing View Source

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ribbon

I'm trying to block "View Source" in Outlook 2016 Mail Item. But the idMso for View Source appears to be incorrect, or it's not even used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="ViewSource" onAction="MyOnAction"/>
    <command idMso="ViewSource" onAction="MyOnGetEnabled"/>
    <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="MyOnAction"/>
    <command idMso="FileSaveAs" getEnabled="MyOnGetEnabled"/>
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

Below is the code in my IRibbonExtensibility object

```
    public void MyOnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
    {
        cancelDefault = true;
    }

    public bool MyOnGetEnabled(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Neither method is called for "View Source". I have confirmed it is wired up correctly as MyOnAction and MyOnGetEnabled is called for FileSave and FileSaveAs.

I actually tried ALL User Interface Control Identifiers in ALL of the outlook spreadsheets available at [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) none of them worked. I have successfully disabled everything but View Source, Read Aloud, Suggest a Feature, Show Training and Get Diagnostic Tools.

Any suggestions on how to block "View Source"? I'm open to all suggestions, including unconventional methods.